# How to decrement value with key value in mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I'm trying to decrement a value using key in mongoose collection.

So, what exactly I want is that *totalPrice* value should be decreased by that product *price* value along with *quantity* by -1.

**Here is my Cart schema:**

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');

let itemSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    product: {
        type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: "Product"
    },
    quantity: Number,
    price: Number
});

var cartSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    userID: {
        type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: 'User'
    },
    items: [itemSchema],
    totalPrice: { type: Number, default: 0 },

});

module.exports = mongoose.model('Cart', cartSchema);
```

**Here is my controller:**

```
module.exports.deleteCartItem = async (req, res, next) => {
    const { productID } = req.params;
    const cart = await Cart.findOneAndUpdate({ 
        userID: req.user._id,
        "items.product": productID
    }, { 
        $inc: { 
            'items.$.quantity': -1,
            totalPrice: -price
        }
    }, { new: true });
}
```

**My cart collection:**

```
{
    "_id": {
        "$oid": "61d49c20e59e3f2690966ffb"
    },
    "totalPrice": 1098,
    "userID": {
        "$oid": "6187fe7cacbffaf7d01a3e23"
    },
    "items": [{
        "_id": {
            "$oid": "61d49c20e59e3f2690966ffc"
        },
        "product": {
            "$oid": "61d1bb34cfa792063ca5d86d"
        },
        "quantity": 2,
        "price": 499
    }, {
        "_id": {
            "$oid": "61d56763340e1607788c8831"
        },
        "product": {
            "$oid": "61d1bc25cfa792063ca5d86e"
        },
        "quantity": 1,
        "price": 100
    }]
}
```

**Final result which I want when deleteCartItem is called:**

```
{
    "_id": {
        "$oid": "61d49c20e59e3f2690966ffb"
    },
    "totalPrice": 599,
    "userID": {
        "$oid": "6187fe7cacbffaf7d01a3e23"
    },
    "items": [{
        "_id": {
            "$oid": "61d49c20e59e3f2690966ffc"
        },
        "product": {
            "$oid": "61d1bb34cfa792063ca5d86d"
        },
        "quantity": 1,
        "price": 499
    }, {
        "_id": {
            "$oid": "61d56763340e1607788c8831"
        },
        "product": {
            "$oid": "61d1bc25cfa792063ca5d86e"
        },
        "quantity": 1,
        "price": 100
    }]
}
```

**Error:**

> ReferenceError: price is not defined
> at module.exports.deleteCartItem (E:\Projects\mean\server\controllers\cartController.js:143:59)

and if I removed the *totalPrice* line the *quantity* is decreasing successfully.

Is there a way to achieve that?? Please help. Thanks

Comment: What isn't working in your code? Does it modify anything? Does it raise an error? Please give a bit more context to your post for us to understand better what's at hand.

Comment: @GaëtanBoyals it gives me error says price is not defined if I removed that line the quantity is decreasing successfully. Let me edit my question for error also.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Indeed, `price` is not defined and thus, when you try to update your total price with `totalPrice: -price`, it raises an error.

Assuming you want to update this key with the `price` contained in your document, you'll have to first retrieve your document and only then update it:

```
module.exports.deleteCartItem = async (req, res, next) => {
  const { productID } = req.params;
  const originalCart = await Cart.findOne({
    userID: req.user._id,
    "items.product": productID
  });
  const priceToReduce = originalCart.items.find(item => item['$oid'] === productID);
  await originalCart.updateOne( {
    $inc: {
      'items.$.quantity': -1,
      totalPrice: -priceToReduce
    }
  });
}
```

Please note that `updateOne` will not return the modified object (as it would with `findOneAndUpdate` with the `new: true` option). If you really need to get the modify object, just do the same code and replace the `updateOne` func with `findOneAndUpdate` (a bit redundant since we already had to retrieve the original object for our purpose):

```
module.exports.deleteCartItem = async (req, res, next) => {
  const { productID } = req.params;
  const originalCart = await Cart.findOne({
    userID: req.user._id,
    "items.product": productID
  });
  const priceToReduce = originalCart.items.find(item => item['$oid'] === productID);
  const newCart = await Cart.findOneAndUpdate({
    userID: req.user._id,
    "items.product": productID
  },
 {
    $inc: {
      'items.$.quantity': -1,
      totalPrice: -priceToReduce
    }
  },
  {
    new: true
  });
}
```

Also, this does not handle any sort of error that could potentially happen (what if `find(item => item.oid === productID);` doesn't find anything? what if `productID` is undefined/null?).

Comment: Thanks for you answer mate it really helped. Also can you please help me in one another problem I have got. Take a look at it please. https://stackblitz.com/edit/node-x12ujs?file=index.js